# Tax implication – Working for California Employer for 2 months from Washington state?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, california, payroll-taxes, remote-work

Moved to Washington (from California) in November,
while continued to work for CA employer  until mid-March.

Payroll was switched to Washington state mid-March.

As I understand,
California taxes will still be owed pro-rated on my total income for the year.

---

**Question** –

Does that fact the work was conducted remotely (from Washington) helps me on California Taxes in any way?

Answer (score 1):

> Does that fact the work was conducted remotely (from Washington) helps me on California Taxes in any way?

No, if you're considered CA resident it doesn't matter where you work. California taxes worldwide income.

If you're not considered CA resident for that period, however, then California has no claim.

You'll need to determine when you stopped being California resident for tax purposes - was it in November, when you moved? Or in March, when you (I'm guessing here) decided to stay in Washington? Based on that you'll attribute the income.

Comment: Since I'm in Washington state for the entirety of 2024, I am Washington tax resident. The question is what happens to the income from CA payroll from Jan to Mar ?

Comment: You'll probably get income tax withholding refunded, but I'm not sure about the SDI

Answer (score 0):

You are subject to income tax by both your state of residence and the state of the source of the income, and if you are taxed by two states on the same income, then you can claim a credit on one of the tax returns. Washington state doesn't have an income tax, so we only need to look at California.

**Was it California-source income?** Income from wages is sourced where the work was performed. See California FTB [Publication 1031](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2023/2023-1031-publication.pdf), page 7, section "Wages and Salaries":

> Wages and salaries have a source where the services are performed.
> Neither the location of the employer, where the payment is issued, nor
> your location when you receive payment affect the source of this
> income.

So assuming you were physically in Washington when performing the work since November, your income since November was not California-sourced.

You should have told (and gotten permission from) your company that you were working from Washington starting in November. Besides income taxes, there are other payroll taxes that depend on where you worked. For example, your company probably deducted California SDI taxes, and the company paid other California employer payroll taxes, for the period after November, that they shouldn't have for someone who wasn't working in California. And there may be some Washington payroll taxes that the company should have deducted or paid, that they didn't. You and the company will need to figure out how to correct those things.

**Were you a California resident?** Again, see [Publication 1031](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2023/2023-1031-publication.pdf). You were a California resident when you were "present in California for other than a temporary or
transitory purpose" or "domiciled in California, but outside California for
a temporary or transitory purpose". Since you moved out of California, were you still domiciled in California, and was your absence from California only for a "a temporary or transitory purpose". These are subjective factors that you will have to determine based on information that we don't have here. If you stopped being a California resident in November, then you would not be subject to California income tax on the non-California-sourced income (e.g. wages for work performed outside California) received since November.

Comment: As per this, then I should not be taxed for Jan to Mar income in California because I was in Washington the entire time?

Comment: @YugalJindle: If you stopped being a California resident from November, then you should not be taxed by California from November to March because you did not have California-sourced income during that time.